# Wrong record in 'service_alarms' table

Tags: zabbix

we have faced with the following inconvenience concerning inconsequential records in "**service_alarms**" table.

As we know "service_alarms" table, should contain records which writen in sequential-ascending order in columns: "servicealarmid", "clock".

But sometimes we meet records in not sequential-ascending order. For example, we have two records:

```
servicealarmid | serviceid | clock      | value 
23182          | 240       | 1497892536 | 3      (1 records, state: service filed - 3)
23194          | 240       | 1497892279 | 0      (2 records, state: service ok - 0)

(1497892536 - Monday, June 19, 2017 5:15:36 PM)
(1497892279 - Monday, June 19, 2017 5:11:19 PM)
```

So my question is: Why date & time in 1-st records greater than in the 2-nd record ? While the values in column - "servicealarmid" is correct, i.e. the sequence in sequential-ascending order.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is likely a race condition between different Zabbix server processes. Is this causing any issues?

Comment: You may be right but how we can check this ?

Comment: This is a normal state of these entries in somewhat recent version (at least 2.x...), so there's not much to investigate. The main question - do you see any issues because of this?

Comment: Yes we have some trouble with that due monitoring SLA by our head manager. So we are periodically recreating these services by Zabbix API but this method is not good solution in general. So I hope there is some correct method to avoid this problem.

Comment: Where exactly do you have a problem, is it in the Zabbix IT service page? Which version of Zabbix? This might be either an already fixed, or some ongoing bug.